# Defining a range from values in another range

Tags: excel, range, vba

I have an excel file of tasks which have either been completed or not, indicated by a Yes or No in a column. Ultimately I am interested in data in a different column but I want to set up the code so it ignores those rows where the task has been completed. So far I have defined the column range containing the yes/no's but I don't know which command to run on this range. I imagine I want to define a new range based on the value in column C.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Notify()
    Dim Chk As Range
    Dim ChkLRow As Long
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo WhatWentWrong

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '--> If the text in column C is Yes then Ignore (CountIF ?)
    '--> Find last cell in the column, set column C range as "Chk"

    Set WS1 = Sheets("2011")

    With WS1
        ChkLRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Chk = .Range("C1:C" & ChkLRow)
    End With

    '--> Else Check date in column H
    '--> Count days from that date until today
    '--> Display list in Message Box
Reenter:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
WhatWentWrong:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Reenter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Would it perhaps be easier to simply define one range based on the values in column C rather than first defining column C as the range and then redefining it?

Thanks

Comment: How about using an autofilter and then getting the visible range? Do you need to use VBA? You can also use a formula to get the total number of days for say "NO".

Comment: The end result I'm trying to achieve is to display a message box for the user on request showing the number of days the tasks not yet completed have been there. I don't want the completed tasks to be hidden all the time and the end user doesn't have the ability to use filters themselves hence using VBA to do it for them when requested.

Comment: So you want the total outstanding days from Col H?

Comment: Yes Column H has the date the task 'arrived' and I want to display a count from then to the current date. The tasks are identified by a 4 digit code in Column A. I envisage the message box saying Task '1234' outstanding for xx days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > > > Yes Column H has the date the task 'arrived' and I want to display a count from then to the current date. The tasks are identified by a 4 digit code in Column A. I envisage the message box saying Task '1234' outstanding for xx days. – Alistair Weir 1 min ago

Is this what you are trying? Added Col I for visualization purpose. It holds no significance otherwise.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Notify()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim Chk As Range, FltrdRange As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim ChkLRow As Long
    Dim msg As String
    On Error GoTo WhatWentWrong

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set WS1 = Sheets("2011")

    With WS1
        ChkLRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your relevant range here
        Set Chk = .Range("A1:H" & ChkLRow)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

        With Chk
            '~~> Filter,
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="NO"
            '~~> Offset(to exclude headers)
            Set FltrdRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            '~~> Remove any filters
            ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

            For Each aCell In FltrdRange
                If aCell.Column = 8 And _
                Len(Trim(.Range("A" & aCell.Row).Value)) <> 0 And _
                Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
                    msg = msg & vbNewLine & _
                          "Task " & .Range("A" & aCell.Row).Value & _
                          " outstanding for " & _
                          DateDiff("d", aCell.Value, Date) & "days."
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With

    '~~> Show message
    MsgBox msg
Reenter:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
WhatWentWrong:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Reenter
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect! In the time that took you all I had managed was to define the filtered visible range! :)

Comment: What is the role of 'Len' ? Same as the formula, count characters in a string?

Comment: Yes. What I am trying to do is check if respective cell in Col A and Col H are not empty

Comment: A little add on to this, is there a simple method to sort the output in the msgbox by the greatest number of days? I have been messing around with applying a sort to the range and then removing it but it seems a long way around the problem. Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to create a temp sheet and store the output there. Sort that data then create the output string. Once the string is created, delete the output sheet.

Comment: Been playing around here, how do I store the output in a new sheet? Have attempted to store it as a range instead of a string but no success. Should I just focus on the `Datediff` command or store the entire msgbox string in a temp sheet sort and then display a 'new' msg box with the sorted info. Thanks! :)

Comment: Should I edit my original question to make this clearer since the comment discussion has been quite long.

Comment: `Should I edit my original question` Ideally no :) as your original question has been answered. You may either ask a new question or continue it here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not brute force it.

```
Dim r_table as Range, i as Integer, N as Integer
' Start from the top
Set r_table = Sheets("2011").Range("C1")
' Find the last entry on column C and count the # of cells
N = Sheets("2011").Range(r_table, r_table.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Dim table_values() as Variant
' This will transfer all the values from the spreadsheet into an VBA array
' and it works super fast. Access values with A(row,col) notation.
table_values = r_table.Resize(N, 5).Value2   ' No. of columns is 5 ?

For i=1 to N
    If table_values(i,1)="Yes" Then   'Check Column C
    Else
       ... table_values(i,5)   ' Column H

    End if
Next i
MsgBox ....
```

This will be super fast, with no flicker on the screen.