# Storing output in temporary sheet for sorting

Tags: excel, vba

Following on from this question, [Defining a range from values in another range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322726/defining-a-range-from-values-in-another-range), (thanks Siddharth!) I want to edit the code to list the the tasks in order by most amount of days to shortest. Had a brief comment chat with Siddharth where he suggested the best way would be to create a temp sheet containing the data, sort that by arrived data and create the message box,  before deleting the temp sheet. Any ideas where to start? Can I export the msg string to a new sheet or does it need to be a variable other t to be stored in a sheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub Notify()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim Chk As Range, FltrdRange As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim ChkLRow As Long
    Dim msg As String
On Error GoTo WhatWentWrong

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WS1 = Sheets("Ongoing")

With WS1
    ChkLRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Set your relevant range here
    Set Chk = .Range("A1:K" & ChkLRow)

    '~~> Remove any filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    With Chk
        '~~> Filter,
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="NO"
        '~~> Offset(to exclude headers)
        Set FltrdRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        '~~> Remove any filters
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

        For Each aCell In FltrdRange
            If aCell.Column = 8 And _
            Len(Trim(.Range("B" & aCell.Row).Value)) <> 0 And _
            Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
                msg = msg & vbNewLine & _
                      "Request for contractor code " & .Range("B" & aCell.Row).Value & _
                      " dispensing month " & .Range("A" & aCell.Row).Value & _
                      " has been in the cupboard for " & _
                      DateDiff("d", aCell.Value, Date) & " days."
            End If
        Next
    End With
End With

'~~> Show message
MsgBox msg
Reenter:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
WhatWentWrong:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Reenter
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look here http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx, which describes almost exactly what you're trying to achieve: create a new sheet, sort new sheet, load sorted values back into an array that you can work with, then delete temporary sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Notify()
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, TmpSht As Worksheet
    Dim Chk As Range, FltrdRange As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim ChkLRow As Long, TSLastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim msg As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Alistair_Weir").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error GoTo WhatWentWrong

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set WS1 = Sheets("Ongoing")

    With WS1
        ChkLRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your relevant range here
        Set Chk = .Range("A1:K" & ChkLRow)

        '~~> Remove any filters
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

        With Chk
            '~~> Filter,
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="NO"
            '~~> Offset(to exclude headers)
            Set FltrdRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            '~~> Remove any filters
            ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

            '~~> Add Temp Sheet
            Set TmpSht = Sheets.Add
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Alistair_Weir"

            '~~> Copy required rows to temp sheet
            TSLastRow = 1
            For Each aCell In FltrdRange
                If aCell.Column = 8 And _
                Len(Trim(.Range("B" & aCell.Row).Value)) <> 0 And _
                Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) <> 0 Then
                    WS1.Rows(aCell.Row).Copy TmpSht.Rows(TSLastRow)
                    TSLastRow = TSLastRow + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With

    With TmpSht
        '~~> Sort Data
        .Columns("A:H").Sort Key1:=.Range("H1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        '~~> Create the message
        For i = 1 To TSLastRow - 1

            msg = msg & vbNewLine & _
                  "Request for contractor code " & .Range("B" & i).Value & _
                  " dispensing month " & .Range("A" & i).Value & _
                  " has been in the cupboard for " & _
                  DateDiff("d", .Range("H" & i).Value, Date) & " days."
        Next

        '~~> Delete the temp sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    '~~> Show message
    MsgBox msg
Reenter:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
WhatWentWrong:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Reenter
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 but rather than building a temp sheet with a slow for each loop, perhaps it would be better to just copy the whole sheet, filter/sort it, build the message box and finally delete the duplicate sheet.

Comment: Spot on Siddharth :) Thanks again.